# Where can I find details of the bus between Tbilisi Georgia and Baku Azerbaijan?

Tags: buses, georgia-country, tbilisi, azerbaijan, baku

WikiTravel and other easily Google-able sources tell me there are buses that run between the Georgian and Azeri capital cities, but no details. I'd like to know the follow for a Chinese guest who just arrived at my hostel in Tbilisi:

- From which bus station in Tbilisi do buses to Baku depart? Ortachala? Didube?
- Is there just one bus company or several?
- How many buses per day?
- What time do the buses leave?
- What is the fare to Baku?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Buses are leaving from the Ortachala bus station
- 4 buses a week
- 20 Lari from Tbilisi to Baku

Source: [OnTheStreet](http://www.onthestreet.jp/busride.php?od=5837baku-tbilisi&type=2)

For times and confirmation of the service, I would still go over to the bus station.

The [Lonely Planet page for Tbilisi](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/georgia/tbilisi/transport/getting-there-away) also mentions buses from Marneuli (30km south of Tbilisi) to Baku.