# Where in Tbilisi can I get very early morning public transport towards Azerbaijan?

Tags: buses, georgia-country, tbilisi, azerbaijan, baku

I will be arriving in Tbilisi on Tuesday 4 april at 04:30, and need to get to Baku from there as quickly as possible by bus.

My questions is, what bus station should I go to for transport at around this time?

Didube, Ortachala, Sadg. Moedani etc?

Any form of public transport is good - buses, mashrutkas, shared taxis, etc - so long as I can reliably find it at around that time in the morning.

Comment: How do you feel about mashrutkas (minibus shared taxis)? They're faster than buses but/and a bit more of an "adventure". I'm pretty sure they start filling around 4am-5am, then each one leaves when it's full

Comment: @user568458 100% fine, just any public transport really (train's not an option as I know it doesn't leave until late afternoon)

Comment: And of: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4364/where-can-i-find-details-of-the-bus-between-tbilisi-georgia-and-baku-azerbaijan?rq=1

Comment: @JonathanReez First one doesn't mention any times, while the second has one dead link and one that doesn't answer my question

Comment: @Crazydre however in the first one the question is the same. Lack of answer is not a reason for a new question. Voting to close.

Comment: @JonathanReez Also this question is specifically about the first bus after 04:30 on a Tuesday

Comment: @Crazydre it is generally agreed that having a single "schedule from X to Y" question is better than 10 questions about "schedule from X to Y at Z time". You may of course post a specific answer in the linked questions.

Comment: @JonathanReez half the question is a dupe, but the other half (*where* in Tblisi to go for early transport that way) is new, a good question (Tblisi's very informal transport system is confusing! I believe buses and mashrutkas use different stations and that mashrurkas start earlier) and not covered by existing questions. I've edited it to focus on the non-dupe half of the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My wife, native of Tbilisi, suggests that all buses and marshrutkas from Tbilisi to Baku leave from Ortachala.  Search around Russian language sites seems to confirm it. (Note: all links below are to Russian language sites.)

[This site](http://travelask.ru/questions/55046-kak-dobratsya-iz-tbilisi-v-baku) talks about actually buses, not marshrutkas, that go from Ortachala to Baku.

[This site](http://za7gorami.ru/avtobusy_i_poezda_v_gruzii) specifically talks about marshrutkas and indicates that the route is from Ortachala to Baku, however this site states 2013 as the date.

[This site](http://permistika.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A2%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8) suggest a couple other options:

- marshrutka from main Railway station to "Red Bridge" (წიტელი ჰიდი - Tsiteli Hidi), then from there buses to Ganja and Baku
- bus from Lilo market near Tbilisi airport to Red Bridge, then buses as above
- marshrutka from main railway station to Marneuli, from there there are buses to Baku.

Finally, that same site suggests that you can take a taxi to the Georgia-Azerbaijan border, which costs about USD $40 ($10 per person, shared ride) - from there, cross the border on foot and take a bus from the Azerbaijani side.

Comment: Do you know which of these have vehicles leaving very early in the morning (around 5am)?

Answer (score 2):

Upon arrival in Tbilisi (04:30 in the morning) I went to the Courtyard Marriott hotel, whose staff has been super helpful to me in the past despite me not staying there. After doing some research, they said there was "unlikely" to be public transport to the border before 11:00

So they got me a taxi to the border for exactly 58 lari (USD 24 or EUR 22), saying that was a pretty good price.

Answer (score 1):

Take a taxi to the border of Azerbaijan from the airport. Cross the border by foot and there are lots of buses and shared taxis waiting on the Azerbaijani side going to Baku.